# No option for Landscape in iPhone Launch Images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is landscape splash screen supported in iPhone? I don't see the option like I do with iPad, as such:

[image]

Comment: btw: what's your deployment target?

Comment: my deployment target is 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them to your assets. I don't think image assets are rendered properly in VS. It doesn't show specialized image for iPhone, iPad, watch etc. Only the generic one.

Another thing you might want to consider is using launch story board and not launch images. That's the new way of doing it or the suggested way by Apple. You have far more control on it.

**Customizing launch images - Manual approach**

Open LaunchImage.launchimage and change the default launch images with your own using the proper resolution for each image (e.g., Default-568h@2x.png should be 640px x 1136px). If your images have different file names then open Contents.json and change the key filename for each image.

[image]

**Xcode WYSIWYG approach**

Drag and drop your Assets.xcassets into Xcode (7.1 or newer version). In the opened window choose LaunchImage and add the proper image for each iOS version and device. Close Xcode and rebuild your Xamarin app to use the new launch images.

Further info : [Human guidelines reference](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/)

Answer (score 2):

That's Visual Studio?

Because I am able to see the iPhone Landscape option in Xamarin Studio.

Try switching on and off the "Assets Catalog" dropdown to see if that helps.

Also if that doesn't work you could change at anytime from Launch image to Launch screen and there you can configure your Storyboard for all different sizes and orientations.

[image]

Note: will check later in VS.

Comment: Is it possible I can just add it in info.plist? If so, would you happen to know what the xml would look like? Specifically the keys?